# Get the numbers at even positions from a file c++

Tags: c++, file, ftell

I wrote this program that is suppose to write some float numbers into a binary file, then read it and display only the numbers located on even positions. Now, i'm having a hard time figuring how to verify the position and to display what's in there. Could anyone please take a look over the code and tell me if there are any mistakes and how could i display something that way? I am also a bit confused about what exactly changes in the way ftell,fgetpos etc. act when they are used in binary files. Any answer would be most appreciated. Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string>

void read(float *p,int n);

void main()
{
    int n;
    float *p,nr;
    char name[20];
    fpos_t poz;
    printf("How many numbers would you like to have in your array?\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    if(!(p=(float*)malloc(n*sizeof(float))))
    {
        printf("Allocation unsuccessful!\n");
        return;
    }

    read(p,n);
    printf("Give the name of the binary file\n");
    scanf("%s",name);

    FILE *f;

    if((f=fopen(name,"w+b"))==NULL)
    {
        printf("The file could not be reached for writing\n");
        return;
    }
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        fwrite((p+i),sizeof(float),1,f);
        fclose(f);
    }

    if((f=fopen(name,"rb"))==NULL)
    {
        printf("The file could not be opened:\n");
        return;
    }

    printf("The numbers at positions 0,3,6 etc. are:\n");
    while ((fread(&nr,sizeof(float),1,f)==1))
    {
        poz=ftell(f);
        if((poz%2)==0)
        {
            printf("%f",nr);
        }
    }
    fclose(f);
    if(p)
        free(p);
    system("pause");
}

void read(float *p,int n)
{
    printf("Introduce the series of numbers:\n");
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        printf("Give the number %d:",i+1);
        scanf("%f",(p+i));
    }
}
```

Comment: It's hard to say what's wrong when you don't say what you expect.

Comment: I want to display only the numbers that are located in the file at even positions.

Comment: `system("pause");` is nonsense. Run your command from the command line to get the output. If you run it form an IDE use the start command that doesn't close the windows without hitting a key ("Start without Debugging" in Visual Studio).

Comment: `free()` accepts a NULL pointer and ignores it. The test `if(p)` is superfluous.

Comment: Reading the file name with `scanf` in insecure. Use `fgets(name, sizeof(name), stdin);` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Errors that I spotted on first look, might be more:

```
void main()
```

`main` should return `int`. The parameter list should be `void`. Your compiler takes your version probably nonetheless:

```
int main(void)
```

Next problem:

```
for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
{
    fwrite((p+i),sizeof(float),1,f);
    fclose(f);
}
```

You close the file after first iteration, then you try to write again. You should close the file when you are finished not after the first write:

```
for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
{
    fwrite((p+i),sizeof(float),1,f);
}
fclose(f);
```

This part does not do what you expect it to do:

```
poz=ftell(f);
if((poz%2)==0)
{
    printf("%f",nr);
}
```

`ftell` returns the position in bytes. Each `float` takes usually 4 bytes. So at this point the position will always be even. You want to check whether it is divided by 8 or better twice the size of `float`:

```
poz=ftell(f);
if(( poz % (2*sizeof(float)) == 0)
{
    printf("%f",nr);
}
```

However it would be much more practicable to use a counter instead:

```
for(int poz=0; fread(&nr,sizeof(float),1,f)==1; poz++)
{
    if((poz%2)==0)
    {
        printf("%f",nr);
    }
}
```

Also is this supposed to be C or C++? The code looks like C but you tagged it C++, also this include would be wrong in C: `#include <string>` should be `#include <string.h>`.

To use `system("pause");` you need to `#include <stdlib.h>`. The line itself is not portable, you should handle this in a different way, see comments above.

Comment: This question might seem stupid but,since i learned c/c++ from so many different sources,this aspect is unclear for me: is <stdio.h> and, for that matter, any library that has ".h" at the end specific to C and conversely for C++?

Comment: In C all of them end in `.h`. In C++ you could also use the `.h` variants but the better way is to use those with `c` prefix. For example `stdio.h` becomes `cstdio` in C++. `string` is special because in C++ there is `string` (which contains the C++-only type `string`) and `cstring` which is equivalent to `string.h`. If however your code is supposed to be C++ rather than C, then you should use entirely different approaches, for example you would use `iostream`s `cin` and `cout` instead of `stdio.h`s `printf` and `scanf`.